# unable to see object from installed package in profile in visual studio code salesforce once retrieved

Tags: salesforcedx, managed-package, profile, vs-code, package.xml

I have a small issue I can't seem to figure out a solution for. I am unable to see objects from managed packages in VSC in Profiles, they are not showing when I try to check the permissions for them.
Any idea why this is happening? I was going over info in the packages as well thinking it could be some permission issue but still can't quite figure out where the problem is coming from exactly. Maybe someone's already stumbled upon this issue before and has a fix for it. Any solution idea would be greatly appreciated!

Later edit:
Please see below screenshot with a few objects having certain permissions on Profile side (under Custom Object Permissions section), yet these are not coming up as  entries in the xml file associated to that particular profile (when trying to use "**SFDX: Retrieve this source from Org**" operation using Visual Studio Code).

[image: Custom Object Permission on Profile side]

Please find below the content of the "manifes/package.xml" file used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>ApexClass</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>ApexComponent</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>ApexPage</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>ApexTestSuite</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>ApexTrigger</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>AuraDefinitionBundle</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>LightningComponentBundle</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>StaticResource</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>Profile</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>Flow</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>PermissionSet</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>RecordType</name>
</types>
<types> 
    <members>*</members>
    <name>CustomTab</name>
</types>
<version>57.0</version>
</Package>
```

Comment: If I understand what you're asking about, then I don't think that should be a surprise. I believe that those permissions are stored in `PermissionSet`s.

Comment: @DerekF updated the post with more details, hope that helps more.

Comment: Neither profiles nor permissionsets retrieved via mdapi/sfdx/ant will not contain wild-carded objects. It is necessary to specify directly in package.xml all objects and fields